# Warning on git commit without GitHub issue number?

Tags: git, github, githooks, pre-commit-hook

Is there a way to have git warn you before finishing a commit, if the commit message does not contain a GitHub issue number?

Comment: Git hooks. This isn't related to Github, it's part of Git itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable the client-side git hooks available on a per repo basis at .git/hooks. Inside this subdirectory you may find a bunch of samples. Here's [a description of the hooks and how to use them](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html).

In this case I think that the most suitable hook is *commit-msg* and you can check if the file that holds the proposed commit log message contains a susbtring in the form *#123*. For that purpose you could use the following regular expression:

```
$(grep '^.*#([1-9][0-9]*).*$' $1)
```